# Goodreads Connect - url for user to grant my application access to their account

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, get, requirejs

What is the url that I can direct a user so they can grant my application access to their goodreads account? I have sourced the goodreads docs at https://www.goodreads.com/api and maybe overlooking something I just cant figure it out.

I require the goodreads' user id to 'Get the books on a members shelf'
https://www.goodreads.com/api#shelves.list

My first obstacle is to enable the dialogue to pop up where the users signs into their goodreads account which effectively grants my application access to their goodreads data.

.....

continuation from question - last parse function "TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined"

```
Meteor.methods({
getGoodreads: function () {
    var oauth = { callback: 'http://localhost:3000/profile/',
    consumer_key: 'keyxkeyx',
    consumer_secret: 'secreckeyxxsecreckeyxx'
},
url = 'http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/request_token';
request.post({url:url, oauth:oauth}, function (e, r, body) {
    var req_data = qs.parse(body);
    var uri = 'http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/authorize'
+ '?' + qs.stringify({oauth_token: req_data.oauth_token});
    var auth_data = qs.parse(body),
oauth =
  { consumer_key: 'keyxkeyx'
  , consumer_secret: 'secreckeyxxsecreckeyxx'
  , token: auth_data.oauth_token
  , token_secret: req_data.oauth_token_secret
  , verifier: auth_data.oauth_verifier
  },
  url = 'http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/access_token';
   console.log(auth_data); // this successfully prints the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret
   request.post({url:url, oauth:oauth}, function (e, r, body) {
     var perm_data =  new qs.parse(body), // "TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined"

     oauth =
    { consumer_key: 'keyxkeyx'
    , consumer_secret: 'secreckeyxxsecreckeyxx'
    , token: perm_data.oauth_token
    , token_secret: perm_data.oauth_token_secret
    },
    url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/topic.xml',
    qs = {user_id: perm_data.user_id,
        key: 'keyxkeyx'};
    request.get({url:url, oauth:oauth, json:true}, function (e, r, user) {
  console.log(user)
   });
  });
});
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The authorization URL for Goodreads is:

```
http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/authorize
```

You can review a (Ruby) code example here https://www.goodreads.com/api/oauth_example

Comment: Thanks. Please see the additional note I added to the question. I am still trying to find the structure of the url which should include my api key. They use oath package which effectively constructs the url and makes the request. However, I would like to know exactly what this structure looks like. Then I use the 'qs' package to request the access token.

Comment: Goodreads uses standard OAuth 1.0; you should be able to leverage  https://github.com/request/request#oauth-signing

Comment: I have gained the oath token and at the stage of making the authenticated api call. Wha may be the possibilities that I get the error on the server 'Cannot call method 'parse' of undefined'?
This is is at the line of code that reads 'var perm_data = qs.parse(body)' from the github link. FYI, I also trued 'var perm_data = qs.stringify(body)' and would then get the error 'Cannot call method 'stringify' of undefined'?

So maybe the data I'm getting is not correct?

Comment: Shall I write out my entire code if it makes it easier?

Comment: I can not find any documentation on this oath1 meteor package https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/oauth1

Comment: I have attempted with the method from  github.com/request/request#oauth-signing and unable to identify why parse or any other function is not working where I have commented in the code. I've added to the question